# Python requests - Upload files with UTF-8 specials chars like "ÄÖÜ" in filename

Tags: python, utf-8, python-requests

I'm using the python3 requests library to post files via a REST-API with this (snippet) code:

```
headers = self.getHeaders()
data = {'options': '{"category":"' + category + '", "keywords":"' + keywords + '", "collectionId":"' + kolid + '", "fileName": "' + filename.decode('utf-8') + '", "dynamicMetadata":' + meta.decode('utf-8') + '}'}
query = {'file': ("'./" + filepath + "'", open(filepath, 'rb'))}
response = requests.post(self.getHost() + "files", headers=headers, data=data, files=(query))
```

While this did upload almost all files, some of them were left out as the api returned a error  saying that it can't process the filename. When watching the logs, all these files have UTF-8 special chars (german umlaute) like "Ä Ö Ü <spaces> " in their filenames. For some reason, my upload path (so the 'query' dictionary) contained unicode characters instead of the decoded UTF-8 special chars.

For example on my linux system the file is stored under
**pictures/attachments/Briefing E-Mailing Verlängerung.pdf** while in the log, the path appears as
**"pictures/attachments/Briefing E-Mailing Verl\u00e4ngerung.pdf"**

When printing the filepath in python (print filepath), I get a clean output, so the filepath/filename must be corrupted by the requests command?

(Versions):

Python 3.5.3 , requests (2.12.4) , Debian 9.13 4.9.0-14-amd64

Answer (score 0):

This is question of decoding on server part, I guess.

For me it seems like `requests` does encoding for filename header for you.

---

I'd also suggest reading through [How to encode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http), answers have a nice collection of related RFCs.